# Make link unclickable under some condition in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

In my ascx file I have a datagrid in this format:

```
<Columns>
                <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="companyName" HeaderText="Company Name">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="40%" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="95%">
                                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="LinkButton" id="btnView" Runat="server" CommandName="ViewDetails" CommandArgument="<%# GetViewUrl((System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)Container.DataItem) %>">
                                        <span ID="SpanTitle" Runat="server">
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"companyName") %>
                                        </span>
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:Label CssClass="DGNormal" ID="lblStatus" Runat="server" text='<%# StatusToText((int) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"statusId")) %>'/>
                                    <asp:Image visible='<%# (bool) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"WMCCMRated") %>' ID="imgProfiled" Runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/WMCCMRated.gif" AlternateText="This company has been competency profiled by WMG" />
                                    <asp:Image Visible='<%# !(Convert.IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"feedback")))%>' ID="feedback" Runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/feedback.gif" AlternateText="The number of feedback this company has been received is ->" ImageAlign="Bottom" Height="18px" Width="12px"/>
                                    <asp:Label CssClass="NormalBold" ID="lblFeedback" Runat="server" text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"feedback") %>' ForeColor="Navy"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
```

So the companyName will be clickable.
Now in my codebehind, I check this condition:

```
// bind the data to the datagrid
            dgCompanies.PageSize = pageSize;
            dgCompanies.DataSource = rdr;

               int j = 0;
               foreach (DataGridItem item in dgCompanies.Items)
               {
                   HtmlGenericControl name = (HtmlGenericControl)item.Cells[j].FindControl("SpanTitle");
                   string drstring = name.InnerHtml.Trim();
                   if (checkfunction(drstring))
                   {
```

Here, if the condition satisfied, I want the link is un-clickable, how could I archive that ?

Comment: `btnView.Enabled = false;` are you searching something like this?

Comment: I don't know, where should I put it and how to make it applied only if condition satisfied ?

Comment: put it inside your if in server side. exactly the code that I have write

Comment: <asp:LinkButton CssClass="LinkButton" id="btnView" Runat="server" CommandName="ViewDetails" CommandArgument="<%# GetViewUrl((System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)Container.DataItem) %>">
                                        <span ID="SpanTitle" Runat="server">
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"companyName") %>
                                        </span>

Comment: I couldn't figure out where the code make the link clickable, so I can't tell you, pls look at my posted code above.

Comment: are you in a masterpage?

Comment: Yes, I posted both ascx and codebehind codes.

Comment: this code is all in your masterpage, Am i wrong?Right click on your master page file in Solution Explorer and select Convert to Web Application it will regenerate the .designer file for you and you will once again be able to access all the master page server controls from code behind.

Comment: Why I need to do that ? I have all the codes here.

Comment: That looks like Visual Studio synchronizing with designer issue

Comment: I see. But I do not get error synchronizing like that before. If I convert to web application will this effect anything to my server and website running ?

Comment: no, try and let me know

Comment: refer [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1006588.aspx?The+name+xxx+Does+Not+Exist+in+the+Current+Context)

Comment: I tried but looks like I cannot convert it due to missing some files problem:"Unable to convert to Web Application format because the page directive is missing in the file 'XXXXX\GoogleNotification.aspx'.Unable to convert to Web Application format because the code-behind file 'XXXXXX\EditKeyProcessesIBS.ascx.cs' does not exist."

Comment: It quite strange since I can find the files there. Only GoogleNotification.aspx is not there but I have GoogleNOtification (asp.net) file

Comment: I tried it again, this time, it said "converted select item to webapp.." but the error is still there: "btnView" does not exist in current context.

Comment: have you one more page with the same code behind wich did not have the control ID? Can you share your project? I'll review it and correct it

Comment: Have you some script that change the id of your linkbutton?

Comment: did you rename your masterpage file?

Comment: Hi, I want to share the project but cannot due to confidential issue, appreciate your intention. I don't think I change any file name. I tried many different id but it cannot recognize, some can recognized, I am not sure how it related to the declaration in .designer.cs. Looks like this is just a bug of VS or the way VS work: http://forums.asp.net/t/1006588.aspx?The+name+xxx+Does+Not+Exist+in+the+Current+Context

Comment: In the link I mentioned they said to turn the build off to avoid the error, but then how could I build the project to make the change effects ?

Comment: Hi faby, I try many different ways it doesn't work. However if I use this command there is no error in recognizing btnView: System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton userLink = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton) item.FindControl("btnView"); Can we make the link disable base on this grammar ?

Comment: Hi, I have two questions. Where is the link button? Master or childpage?  Where is the code where you are trying to get the linkbutton? Master or child? If they are in different location I didn't understand and I can help you to find the solution

Comment: I don't know what is master or child page, but the link button is in ascx file, the code is in codebehind file.

Comment: I have updated my answer. try that

Answer (score 0):

This is from [Disables the linkbutton](http://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/archive/2009/10/03/disabling-linkbutton-hyperlink-and-imagebutton-completely.aspx)

```
/// <summary>
/// Disables the link button.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="linkButton">The LinkButton to be disabled.</param>
public static void DisableLinkButton(LinkButton linkButton)
{
    linkButton.Attributes.Remove("href");
    linkButton.Attributes.CssStyle[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color] = "gray";
    linkButton.Attributes.CssStyle[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Cursor] = "default";
    if (linkButton.Enabled != false)
    {
       linkButton.Enabled = false;
    }

    if (linkButton.OnClientClick != null)
    {
        linkButton.OnClientClick = null;
    }
}
```

check this also [how-to-enable-or-disable-linkbutton](http://www.aspnetajaxtutorials.com/2009/05/how-to-enable-or-disable-linkbutton-in.html)

Comment: I don't want to disable all the link. Only the one at condition if satisfied, other links should work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Put inside your serverside function inside the if the following code

```
btnView.Enabled = false;
```

based on your request

```
((System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)item.FindControl("btnView")).Enabled= false;
```

Comment: then how buttonView = true again ? because some links need to work, only inside if condition make it unclickable

Comment: it said btnView doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: which is the id of the linkbutton that you are going to disable?

Comment: Actually, I tried item.FindControl("btnView")).Enabled= false; but I still can click it.

Comment: try this `((System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)dgCompanies.Item[0].FindControl("btnView")).Enabled= false;` where 0 is the index of the item